# asp.net MVC adding Multiple classes not giving expected result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Code**

*C#*

```
 public static class MyClass
    {
        public static object Foo = new { @class = "foo" };
        public static object Barbaz = new { @class = "bar baz" };
    }
```

*cshtml*

```
<div @MyClass.Foo></div>
<div @MyClass.Barbaz></div>
```

---

**Desired HTML result**

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo bar"></div>
```

---

**Actual HTML result**

```
<div {="" class="foo" }=""></div>
```

*(works, but looks wrong)*

```
<div {="" class="bar" baz="" }=""></div>
```

*(doesn't work, and looks even more wrong)*

---

How should I declare `Foo` and `Barbaz` to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it a little different:
C#

```
public static class MyClass
{
        public static string Foo = "foo";
        public static string Barbaz = "bar baz";
}
```

VIEW

```
<div class="@MyClass.Foo"></div>
<div class="@MyClass.Barbaz"></div>
```

reusing in action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("mylink","@Url.Action("Index","Home")", new {@class=MyClass.Foo})
```

Comment: The direction this is going shows me I indeed should avoid this. However, out of sheer interest in understanding the mechanics I tried your answer (changing 'bar baz' with 'a b c'), but it results in the following HTML: class="'a" b="" c&#39;=""

Comment: I totally agree that you should avoid it and as I already wrote:  
If you declare them as strings, you could still reuse them for action links: `Html.ActionLink("abc","abc", new {@class=MyClass.Foo})`

Answer (score 1):

`class` is an html attribute, IMHO, It is not a good idea to render that attribute itself from server using a variable. The value is fine.

Use simple string type which holds just the css class name

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string Foo =  "foo" ;
    public static string Barbaz = "bar baz" ;
}
```

and the view

```
<div class="@MyClass.Foo"></div>
```

Your approach in the question, will work with `ActionLink` helper method call as the mvc framework accepts an anonymous object and build the html attributes from that. You cannot use that as it is with your normal html markup as there is nothing to convert the anonymous object to the corresponding html markup. Although you can write some code to do that, It will make your code messy. Remember , The clean approach is to write readable code (normal html markup as much as you can in the view file). This the whole reason behind the asp net team to bring the new [tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) so designers can build the page without worrying too much about server code / any magic helper methods etc

I would lean towards avoiding to call magic helper methods in my view code. I prefer to keep it as normal HTML code as much as i can.

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking. For me it looks quite a different behavior.

Comment: @RazvanDumitru indeed, there's a difference. The way I have my classes declared as objects, I can use the same static object in '@Html.ActionLink(string, string, string, null, MyClass.Foo)', and it's also less code. Shyju, is it also possible to declare the 'class' identifier in my static object, so that I can use the same cshtml and get my desired result?

Comment: @DaniëlCamps It (your approach in the question) will work with ActionLink helper method call as the mvc framework accepts an anonymous objects and build the html attributes from that. You cannot use that plain in you normal html markup as there is nothing to convert the annonymous object to this html markup. Although you can write some code to do that, It will make your code messy. Remember , in asp.net core, we have tag helpers which helps us write clean HTML code. IMHO you should try to follow that. That is more cleaner than building your method convert the annon object to HTML markup

Comment: @Shyju thank you for the clarification. So from a best practices point of view, you recommend the string approach for flat HTML. What do you recommend for action links?

Comment: Yes.IMHO, The clean approach is to write readable code (normal html markup as much as you can in the view file). This the whole reason behind the asp net team to bring the [new tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) so designers can build the page without worrying too much about server code / any magic helper methods etc.

Comment: @DaniëlCamps From a best practices point of view, you can try to get into tag helpers when you see the opportunity (generic div for an ad, spans, alerts for 50% off, etc). It always depends. As Shyju said, you can go with normal html markup if you only have a couple of internal classes. There is no need to add more non-readability to your product.

Comment: If you declare them as strings, you could still reuse them for action links:
`Html.ActionLink("abc","abc", new {@class=MyClass.Foo})`

Comment: @AlexArt. yeah that's indeed what I was thinking about, thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1):

Do not use objects but strings in properties like this:

```
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static string Foo = "foo";
        public static string Barbaz = "bar baz";
    }
```

and in view set up code:

```
<div class = "@MyClass.Foo"></div>
<div class="@MyClass.Barbaz"></div>
```

Side note: you will probably need to revise your logic as setting css classes from c# backend is not something you should do very often. Try to avoid that. Instead use flags based on which you will have appropriate css classes applied in view.